# MapView doesn't take up full screen

Tags: android

I hate to bother you all again, as this is probably me, a newbie, making some big blunder, but I'm baffled as to why my mapview only takes up a fraction of the screen.  I've been following tutorials.  My layout:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

                

  <com.google.android.maps.MapView 

        android:id="@+id/mapView"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:enabled="true"

        android:clickable="true"

        android:apiKey="MY_API_KEY"

        />



<RelativeLayout>`

The specified screen resolution is, as in the droid, 854x480.  It shows up in the emulator in horizontal mode (wide, not very tall).  The map starts about a third of the way from the left and ends about a third of the way from the right.  It starts at the top and ends about a third of the way from the bottom of the screen.  I have no clue why that would happen, as I specified "fill_parent".

Thoughts?

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure this one out.  I've tried a variety of things.  I switched to a linearlayout, as one page I saw recommended.  I tried spelling out absolute layout widths.  I tried all sorts of stuff.  The map stubbornly remains surrounded by black on all sides.

Comment: One thing I noticed was that when I specified widths and heights that were really large, way bigger than the screen, the map showed up as pure white instead of as a map.  But it still had the black all around the map as described above.  Really frustrating.

Another observation worth making: At the top of the map is a little bar that has the program's name.  It, like the map, is truncated by the black bars on either side and only takes up 1/3 of the width, whether in landscape or portrait mode.

Still trying to figure this thing out...

Comment: I found how to get rid of the title bar at the top, with Theme.NoTitleBar.  However, Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen didn't do the trick I was hoping; it just removed the status bar from the top, but didn't do anything about the map not stretching to the boundaries.  More trudging...

Comment: Update: ALL apps that are available as new app templates are having the same problem!  I wonder if it's something about the build or deployment process that's messing up?  The apps that come by default on the emulator take up the fullscreen.

Comment: Update: The images look like the ones at the bottom of this page, esp. the VGA image.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I'm still trying to figure out how to make use of this info.  A supports-screens tag didn't do the trick.  :P

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  I know *what* broke it, although I don't know *why* it broke it.  I had manually spelled out the Droid's resolution instead of selecting a preset, but had left unchanged the DPI from the initial 160.  For some reason, this caused all apps deployed from eclipse to show up as too small, yet all apps that came with the emulated droid were a perfectly normal size.  Go figure.  :P

Either way, the fix was to rebuild the droid using a resolution preset.